# Is there any way to make an adapter / wrapper pattern in annotations?

Tags: java, design-patterns, architecture, osgi, adapter

Following some principles that say that software (especially business logic) should be "framework independent", I would like to know if it is possible to apply some wrapper / adapter in libraries that are based on Annotations?

We can take as an example, in Java the [OSGi Declarative Services (DS) Annotations framewor](https://docs.osgi.org/download/r6/osgi.cmpn-6.0.0.pdf), which uses annotations to create "Components" and use, and abuse Dependency Injection.

```
@Component(name = "Example", scope = ServiceScope.SINGLETON, service = ExampleSomething.class, immediate = true)
class Example implements ExampleSomething {
  @Override
  public void doSomething() {

  }
}

interface ExampleSomething {
  void doSomething();
}


@Component(name = "ExampleRef", scope = ServiceScope.SINGLETON, service = ExampleSomethingToRef.class, immediate = true)
class ExampleRef implements ExampleSomethingToRef {
  
  @Reference
  ExampleSomething exampleSomething;
  
  @Activate
  void onInit(Map<String, Object> properties) {
    
  }
  
  @Override
  public void makeSomething() {

  }
}

interface ExampleSomethingToRef {
  void makeSomething();
}
```

Comment: Olviera You might want to _clarify_ what you're looking for. Since these are build time annotations, they have no runtime coupling. I.e. you can use them in any other context and these components are testable without running OSGi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `FindHook` to hide the service you want to wrap and publish instead the wrapper with the same properties/interfaces as the underlying service.

IIRC, the OSGI Spec describes this scenario : https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.servicehooks.html#d0e45668